# Windows 8 & ASP.NET MVC & IISExpress low performance on start

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, windows-8, iis-express

We have a pretty big ASP.NET MVC project with a lot of Areas, controllers etc. Everything was fine until I installed the project on my laptop - Windows 8.1, Intel Core i5, 12 GB RAM, 7200 HDD. The project starting time (F5) become extremely slow. I'm waiting for 3-5 minutes until the home page appears in the browser. First I thought that the problem is in my laptop, and I rent a VPS - Windows Server 2012, Intel Xeon 4 core, 14GB Ram, SSD. But the situation is the same - I'm waiting for a while before the first page appears.

**What I've tryed**:

1. batch="false" in Web.config (compile optimization was also disabled/enabled)
2. Disabled Resharper
3. Disabled IntelliTrace
4. Disabled MiniProfiler for EF
5. Disabled Firewall
6. No anti-virus software
7. Enabled the concurrent build in the Resharper's [God Mode](http://anything-dotnet.blogspot.de/2012/07/resharpers-hidden-gems-or-god-mode.html)
8. The RAM disk was also used
9. dotTrace profiler shows that over 70% of execution time takes the unmanaged code
10. Debugging symbols caching

The problem has already appeared on PCs of a couple of my collegues. Situation is the same - Windows 8.1, pretty powerful hardware - impossible to work with Visual Studio. *Please, if anybody knows where the problem is let us know.*

**P.S.** **We use Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, ASP.NET MVC 5, EntityFramework 6.**

Comment: I'm getting similar symptoms. Very simple MVC 5 project, running in `IIS Express`, literally just one controller and no other config. When I press `CTRL + F5`, or just `F5` to start with debugger, the browser just sites there for ages before the homepage appears. I'm using VS2013 on Windows 8.1 - with plenty of RAM.

Comment: IIS Express starts slow, within VS, if it cold starts. Meanwhile, VS browser link might add extra delay. If possible, run failed request tracing to know deeper, or switch to full IIS.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @LexLi, but browser link was the first which I disabled.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me: Start a 2nd instance of VisualStudio with a minimal Webapp in IIS Express in debug mode and let it still run while working with your 1st Instance VS and do your work!